# how to return value from if condition inside loop and use it in first of loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop to create paid number like 040-050 here is the code

```
    start_num = 40
end_num = 50
painumreturn = ''
count = 0
for painum in range(start_num, end_num):
    if not painumreturn:
        painumbe = painum
    else:
        painumbe = painumreturn

    painumber = str(painumbe).zfill(3)

    if painumber == '044':
        if count == 2:
            painumreturn = ''
            count == 0
            painumber = int(painumbe) +1
        else:  
         painumreturn = painumber
         count = count +1
         print(count)
    print(painumber)
```

#output

```
040
041
042
043
1
044
2
044
45
047
048
049
```

it should from here to continue the first make the 45 with out 045 and it jump from 046 so this is the right out but

```
2
044
045
046
047
048
049
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. What happens (output), what should happen/be shown? Edit the question to show it.

Comment: i edit it see it

Comment: You can use an additional variable to flag (`True` or `False`) if condition was already met. In an additional `if`-clause you can check this flag and print the number (or not) depending on the flag.

Comment: What is the difference between the output of `for p in range(start_num, end_num): print(f"{p:03.0f}")` and what you want as output?

Comment: After the condition is right should all the values be `044`?

Comment: no the idea to start from 044 when it reach it and continue to the end

Comment: So what should it print? Or does the printing not matter? What should the correct answer do?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
# intialize varibales:
start = 40
end = 50

# iterate over given range:
for number in range(start, end):

    # skip values less than 44:
    if number < 44:
        continue

    # use zfill to format number:
    formatted_number = str(number)
    formatted_number = formatted_number.zfill(3)

    # print result:
    print(formatted_number)
```

Output:

```
044
045
046
047
048
049
```

Comment: I would rather put the code inside the if, especially when we can just use a one liner to print it but using `continue` is definitely a good option too.

Comment: the idea to update the value of painumreturn from empty to the current value

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy storing your result as a list, you can use list comprehension to complete your task in one line.

```
numbers = [str(num).zfill(3) for num in range(start, stop) if num >= 44]

#['044', '045', '046', '047', '048', '049']

print(*numbers, sep='\n')

#044
#045
#046
#047
#048
#049
```

Comment: the idea to update the value of painumreturn from empty to the current value

Comment: Does this not adhere to the result you're looking for? `start from 044 and iterate until end`. This seems like a very logical, easy to read way to get the result you're aiming for. Is there a specific reason you need it to operate that way?

Comment: yup there is some condition i wanna use it for

Comment: If you know prior that `painumreturn` is `044`, why are you not just looping 44-50?

Answer (score 0):

Skip all items that a condition satisfies:

```
start_num = 40
end_num = 50

for painum in range(start_num, end_num):
    if painum < 44:
        continue

    print(f"{painum:03.0f}")
```

Only do something for items that a condition satisfies:

```
start_num = 40
end_num = 50

for painum in range(start_num, end_num):
    if painum >= 44:
        print(f"{painum:03.0f}")
```

Comment: the idea to update the value of painumreturn from empty to the current value

Answer (score 0):

Printing one element twice:

```
start_num = 40
end_num = 50
painumreturn = ''

for p in range(start_num, end_num):
    if p == 44:
        print(f"{p:03.0f}")
        painumreturn = f"{p:03.0f}"

    print(f"{p:03.0f}")
```

output:

```
040
041
042
043
044
044
045
046
047
048
049
```

Comment: right but it should continue not print only the number mean increase from 044 after set it

Comment: How about now :)

Comment: good but what i mean to do it just one more then increase that it like to check if this second time or first time if it second increase if it first to do from the value

Comment: So we don't print "044"?

Comment: we print it like we do it a gain

Comment: So it should print `040 041 042 043 044 044 045 046 047 048 049`?

Comment: so far so good but this is for print it twice not to do the for from the value and check it if it the second time this value and increase the number

Comment: if painumber == '044':
        if count == '2':
            painumreturn = ''
            count == '0'
            painumber +1
        else:  
         painumreturn = painumber
         count +1

Comment: What should `painumreturn` be at the end of it?

Comment: when the condition is true painumreturn should take this value then we check if this value inside the     if '044' in painumber: we check if this number is it the second time we check it or the first if it the first we set painumber to the value if it the second we will not set the value and continue increaseing

Comment: I'm sorry but, your question is becoming extremely vague and the example clearly doe's not show the outcome you're seeking. Most answers have provided an answer based on your question an example. Could you take another shot and writing the question, with a new example? This seems to be going around in circles.

Comment: I agree make a more clear question and delete this one.

Comment: This is my last attempt but you should make a clear question because other people might find it useful too. Other people will not find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
start_num = 40
end_num = 50
painumreturn = ''
count = 0
for painum in range(start_num, end_num):
    if not painumreturn:
        painumbe = painum
    else:
        painumbe = painumreturn

    painumber = str(painumbe).zfill(3)

    if painumber == '044':
        if count == 1:
            painumreturn = ''
            count == 0
        else:  
            painumreturn = painumber
            count = count +1
    print(painumber)
```

output:

```
040
041
042
043
044
044
046
047
048
049
```

Thanks!

Best regards.